# Getting first and last date of selected month c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetimepicker

before getting started I want to tell that I already know how to select the 1st and last date of the current month. But, my question is different, I want to select the 1st and the last date of the **selected** month using `date-time picker` in c# `winforms`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();          

    MonthYearDT();
}

private string MonthYearDT()
{

        dTMY.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dTMY.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        dTMY.ShowUpDown = true; // to prevent the calendar from being displayed


        return dTMY.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
}

private void BtnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .
    .
    .
    .

      monthYear = MonthYearDT();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In the above, the value of `monthYear` is `2019-12-19`. It can be changed to any month. I want to get the 1st `2019-12-01` and last date `2019-12-31` of the selected month.

How can I do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing anything firstly change the function `MonthYearDT()` from `string` to `DateTime`

```
private DateTime MonthYearDT()
{
        dTMY.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dTMY.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM";
        dTMY.ShowUpDown = true; // to prevent the calendar from being displayed
        dTMY.Enabled = false;
        return dTMY.Value; 
}
```

Getting the first is easy. Just create a new `DateTime` like so

```
DateTime selectedDate = MonthYearDT();

var first = new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1);
```

getting the second is just as easy. Use `first`, add one month and subtract one day like so

```
var second = first.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

firstDate = first.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
lastDate = second.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I am getting error `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no accessible extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found`

Comment: Same as for month also

Comment: Change the `MonthYearDT()` to return a `DateTime` instead of a `string` and return `dTMY.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Universal truth is that the first day of any month would always be same.

And to get the last date below DateTime function can be used. You need year also along the month to get the last day

```
var lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
var lastDayDate = new DateTime(year, month, lastDay);
```